# Remote Desktop Software

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, vnc, nx, linux-mint

I'm going to be going to college soon and the laptop I have is rather pathetic. I'd like to run Linux Mint on my desktop and remotely access it using my laptop. Unlike what people usually use Remote Desktop programs for, I want my laptop to, in essence, BE my desktop. To use it's processing power and everything...basically just be a remote screen and keyboard. I THINK that might be FAT client, but I'm not sure.

I know of VNC, x2go, FreeNX, and NoMachines. Which of these would be best for what I want, or is there something better?

Thanks!

Comment: too little info... whats the connection like?  You are basically doing something that has been done for over 30 years.  You ARE doing what most people use remote desktop for... nothing special here.  By desktop do you mean the X11 server?  Why not just use the X11 client on your laptop?

Comment: Depends. Which operation system do you use on your laptop? The real issue I see here is how you are going to connect to your (presumably) home desktop. VPN or a secure web site like logmein.com or pcanywhere.com? That aside, you are asking the question on the wrong website. This is a site for programmers and programming/software development related questions. Your question fits into neither.

Comment: Well I'd be directly connecting to my desktop through the internet using it's external IP address. It would be hooked up off campus, while I would be using the internet on campus to connect to it. And yes I want to be able to see the X window server that my desktop uses on my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

For that purposes it's overkill what you are trying to do. You'll be fine dual booting in your laptop.  In a decent Win or Mac computer you can run a Linux Virtual machine with e.g. [virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/).

Or you can boot with an external HD or pendrive with [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)